# cosmos not returning any records when using table api

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cosmosdb

How do you query the database to return records using the table api?

My documents look like this:

```
{
  "id": "069c2612-355a-4659-b680-048b7ef19f5c",
  "_rid": "3RtVAMJ2mQkBAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": "dbs/3RtVAA==/colls/3RtVAMJ2mQk=/docs/3RtVAMJ2mQkBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-8cc3-3e8f580501d4\"",
  "FieldType": "InsuranceCode",
  "TranslateFrom": "XTH",
  "TranslateTo": "removed",
  "SourcePaerty": "TMH",
  "DestinationParty": "GE",
  "Key": "/TMH/GE/InsuranceCode",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1544032329
}
```

I'm attempting to simply read records using the table api for cosmos:

```
public static IEnumerable<Translation> ConnectAndFetch () {
    var connectionString = "myconnectionstring;";
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse (connectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient ();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference ("translationCollection");

    TableQuery<Translation> query = new TableQuery<Translation> ();

    return table.ExecuteQuery (query);
}
```

**However, no records are returned!**

What am I doing wrong? How do I query my dataset and return records?

Example of usage is below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mystuff = CosmosTableConnector.ConnectAndFetch().Take(5).ToList();
    }
```

And as you can see 0 results:

[image]

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tried below table api .net code to query my data in cosmos db table api. It works for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //CloudTable table = CreateTableAsync("j").Result;
        //var result = QueryTableAsync("test").Result;
        TableQuerySegment <ResponseEntity>  resultE=  QueryTableAsync("test").Result;
        foreach(ResponseEntity re in resultE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp:   "+re.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("execute done");

        Console.ReadLine();

} 

public static async Task<TableQuerySegment<ResponseEntity>> QueryTableAsync(string tableName)
        {
            string cst = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***;TableEndpoint=https://***.table.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/;";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(cst);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

            var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                "Timestamp",
                QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-10).Date);

            Console.WriteLine(filter);

            var query = new TableQuery<ResponseEntity>();

            var result = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

            return result;

    }
```

My data :

[image]

Output:

[image]

Based on your sample data, I surmise that your data is stored inside the Cosmos [SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet),not [Table API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet). Then are different database.

If you want to query sql api, you need to refer to this sdk:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: why are you assuming my data is in cosmos sql api and not cosmos table api? im not sure how your example is helpful, since it's not doing what i am doing

Comment: because i notice that your sample document contains _etag,_ts,_self columns.Per my knowledge,those are system generated properties in cosmos db sql api. Of course,you could add these column in table api.

Comment: And my example is not sql api, it's table api, have your tried it?